# Removing CCLabelTTF in a next-back button action

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I don't know how to remove my label string. The thing is like this, y push the next button and remove the label, to add the next label (and the same with the back button)
Here is the method that starts when pushing a next/back button:

```
-(void)showStoryContentWithIndex:(int)index
{
    [self removeChild:card cleanup:YES];

    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Names" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray* contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    CCLabelTTF *truckName = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[contentArray objectAtIndex:currentIndexSelected]  fontName:CUSTOM_FONT_NAME fontSize:80];

    truckName.position = ccp(500, 220);
    [self addChild:TName];

    NSString * cardSpriteName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",currentIndexSelected];
    card = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:cardSpriteName];
    [card setPosition:ccp (500,500)];
    [card setOpacity:255];
    [self addChild:card z:4];
}
```

So, there I need to implement a way to remove a label, I was trying to use removeChild, but nothing appeared there.

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

keep an iVar for the next and previous labels, and instead of removing them, why dont you

```
// in .h

CCLabelTTF *_nextLabel, *_previousLabel;

// somewhere in init 

_nextLabel = [CCLabelTTF ...];
[self addChild:_nextLabel]              
_previousLabel = [CCLabelTTF ...];
[self addChild:_previousLabel]              


// and finally, when you update 

[_nextLabel setString:@"new next"];
[_previousLabel setString:@"new previous"];
```

EDIT :

```
NSString* newNext = [dic objectForKey:@"keyForNext"];
[_nextLabel setString:newNext];
```